# Grouping content by category - Drupal

Tags: drupal, content-type, drupal-views, cck, categories

is there a good way of grouping content up by category.

I wish I could have a CCK category field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Taxonomy. It has good integration with views. We use it to group portfolio projects by taxonomy word on our portfolio.

http://www.inclind.com/our-work/index.htm

Using only views and taxonomy for data.

Comment: Found that out! Excellent response! A++ =D